# How to separate $('ul li').text by comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
<ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul li').text();
```

**Current Output**

```
List1List2
```

**Expected Output**

```
List1,List2
```

**Question**

How to separate them by comma?

Comment: Nice and clean question, so rare =P up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get that texts into an array and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it afterwards,

```
var values = $('#tags li').map(function(){ 
  return $(this).text(); 
}).get().join(','); // List1,List2
```

Comment: The answer is correct, however for newbies you should provide a brief explanation on how this works.

Comment: I've dynamic ul li tags, and I wanted to set the value to the output. How could I do that? $('#tags li') = values; is not working for me as values is the expected output.  But how could I render it on the display?